# Почему не работаетCount(*) as?

Tags: yii2

Вот так пишу:

```
$top=Watch::find()
            ->select(['fl_serial.*,fl_watch.*,COUNT(fl_watch.active=1) AS total_count'])
            ->joinWith('serial','fl_watch.id_serial=serial.id')
            ->groupBy('fl_watch.id_serial')
            ->orderBy(['total_count'=>SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(10)
            ->all();
```

Потом обработать так:

```
foreach($top as $post) {
    $posts[]=$post->total_count;
}
```

Получаю:

> Getting unknown property: common\models\Watch::total_count

Как правильно обработать `COUNT( * ) AS total_count`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже все так. Попробуйте просто добавить свойство `total_count` в модель `Watch`, оно должно быть публичным.